# jQuery works in Firefox but not in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following accordion-script from jQuery that works perfectly in Firefox but not in IE7. In IE7 I can see the 5 sections, however, without the accordion-effect.

```
 <!doctype html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <title>jQuery UI Accordion - Default functionality</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"  
     type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

   <script>
     $( function() {
       $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
     });
   </script>

    <form id="dialogform" title="Edit User" action="">
  <div class="edit">
    <div>
      <div id="dataEdit">
        <div>Name</div>
        <input class="name input" type="text" name="name" minlength="2" type="text" required aria-required="true">
        <div>Email</div>
        <input class="mail input" type="email" name="email" required aria-required="true">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<form id="dialogNewUser" title="New User" action="">
  <div class="edit">
    <div>
      <div id="dataNew">
        <label> Name</label>
        <input class="name input" name="name" minlength="2" type="text" required aria-required="true">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input class="mail input" type="email" name="email" required aria-required="true">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

**Question**

What do I have to do to run this script in IE7?

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug with the IE 7, you have to set "animated : false" and "autoHeight : false" to fix it.

```
$(window).load(function() {
        $('div.accordion').accordion({
            heightStyle: "content",
            animated : false,
            autoHeight : false
        });

    });
```

Also, check your anchor tags.  IE7 doesn't like them to be around dt tags.  Here's a JSFiddle that should work in IE7, and you can use it as a base to fix what you have:

http://jsfiddle.net/y6m2N/21/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment! Since I am a beginner, could you please tell me where I can do this? I didn´t find it in the jquery-ui.js file. Or do I have to add this code in the html-file?

Comment: It's javascript that you'd add to the aspx page.

Comment: Thanks again! For IE11, is it the same solution?

Comment: Not sure about that, but if you find out let me know!  I'm having trouble with that one myself.  ;o)